# how to get the name of method in current class

Tags: java

Hello
in my java class Toto, I have 3 static methods
I would like to know when I'm in one of these methods , how to get and display the name of package.class.methode in the try catch bloc ?
I tried in methodeA:

```
public static void methodeA(){

try{
system.out.println("I do something");

}
catch(Exception e){
system.out.println("failed" +e.getClass().getMethods().toString());
}
```

but it is not working, how also could I show it in try ?
thanks

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers to your questions yet - this may discourage people from helping you. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details on how to do it.

Comment: Why do you require this to get by method calls ? You could directly hard code it as you know package name, class name and method name.

Comment: Have you considered just using a logging framework and logging the exception? Most logging frameworks will print a stacktrace, which is better than just printing the name of the current class and method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.printStackTrace();` - that will print the whole exception stracktrace - i.e. all the methods + line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: but how could I call e.printStackTrace(); ?

Comment: if I try :system.out.println("failed" +e.getStackTrace()); it displays some @adresses...

Comment: you call it just by... calling it. You don't need to wrap in a println. As the name says, it will print the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example below:

```
public class A 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new A().intermediate();   
    }
    void intermediate() 
    {
        new A().exceptionGenerator();
    }
    void exceptionGenerator()
    {
      try
      {
         throw new Exception("Stack which list all calling methods and classes");
      }
      catch( Exception e )
      {
         System.out.println( "Class is :" + e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + 
                             "Method is :" + e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

         System.out.println("Second level caller details:");
         System.out.println( "Class is :" + e.getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() + 
                             "Method is :" + e.getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());

      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have ou noticed you already have the information in your exception's stacktrace ?

Indeed, Exception class provides a [`getStackTrace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29) method that returns you an array of [StacktraceElement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html). Each of these elements gives you class name, method name, and some other details. What you can do is look in this array if you find one of your three methods, and voila !

However, be warned that detection of method name may fail if you use an obfuscator on your code.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred option.....

```
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or (not a wise option since you don't know what exception is thrown an you have no Stack Trace Elements printed).

```
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't show me the name , in the console I see only "run" I do not know I haven't wrote it and my class and methode doesn't have "run" name ??

Comment: I tried : catch(Exception e) { 
    System.out.println(e.getStacktrace()[0].getMethodName()); 
}

Comment: Are there any exception thrown?

Comment: the java tries to access to an object and could't but no message shown with catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e.getStacktrace()[0].getMethodName()); }

Comment: It does work for me....make sure you typed `e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()` (capital "S" and capital "T")

Comment: I tried the following : System.out.println("failure in file "+e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() ); and in the console I got : failure in file ensureUniqueKey

Comment: It showed your method name called `ensureUniqueKey`. To get file name, do `e.getStackTrace()[0].getFileName()`

Comment: sorry, but ensureUniqueKey isn't the name of my method !

Comment: my methode name is SelectButton()

Comment: then get the last `getStackTrace()` and see if that is it....otherwise you'll have to iterate until you get to the method...the thing is, the method operation that threw the exception is put on top of the stack element trace and the stack trace goes down the list till the parent that ran it (e.g `public static void main`).

Comment: JIC: try `e.getStacktrace()[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you throw the exception,  is affecting your performance. Is not needed throw the exception,

```
public class AppMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   new AppMain().execute();
 }

 private void execute(){
   RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException();
   StackTraceElement currentElement = exception.getStackTrace()[0];

   System.out.println(currentElement.getClassName());
   System.out.println(currentElement.getMethodName());
 }
}
```