# How can I get the name of a method without using class.getDeclaredMethod

Tags: java

How can I get the name of a method just like I can get the name of a class?
(RandomClass.class.getName())

Hardcoding won't work because the obfuscator destroys it.

Reason:
I'm injecting methods like this:

```
        MethodNode getLocalPlayer = GetterAdapter.insert(false, true, "getLocalPlayer", "Lvanquish/accessors/Player;", "client", "yD", "LQZ;");
        classNode.methods.add(getLocalPlayer);

        //class client implements my interface which contains the method getLocalPlayer

      public interface Client {

         public int[] getPlayerIndices();

         public Player getLocalPlayer();

         public Player[] getPlayers();

         public int getBaseX();

         public int getBaseY();

         public int getCameraX();

         public int getCameraY();

      }

        //when I obfuscate my files getLocalPlayer get's a name like a2
        //when you look above you see that the method name was hard code and so
        // will it create an error
```

Declared method wont work here, because I don't know the method name and there are like 4 vars of the same type.

Would this work or would it be a mess?

```
    @DataMap.varDetails(name = "getPlayerIndices")
public int[] getPlayerIndices();
```

Comment: You can throw an exception, catch it and look at the stack trace. Just kidding, don't...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864175/how-to-get-the-name-of-method-in-current-class?rq=1

Comment: Why do you need to?  (This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Sorry, but could you say something more about why you don't want to use `getDeclaredMethod()`?

Comment: @Pshemo OP wants to find out a method's name, not find a method by a known name.

Comment: @eran Your suggestion is actually the best way, IMO. Just one thing: no need to *throw* an exception, *creating* is all it takes.

Comment: Often reflection is used where it isn't actually needed.  Perhaps instead you could wrap each Client in some common interface, such as PlayerGetter?

Answer (score 0):

You would need each of the methods you want to refer to reflectively do something like this:

```
static String baseXName;

public int getBaseX() {
  if (baseXName == null)
    baseXName = detectMyName();
  ... the actual code of the method ...
}
```

and `detectMyName()` would, as @eran suggests in the first comment to your question, instantiate an `Exception` and retrieve the actual runtime name of the calling method from its stacktrace. You can avoid a tiny bit of overhead by obtaining the stacktrace without instantiating exception if you call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

it show you the stack of your calling method in current thread.
**Best of luck :)**